# CakePHP: Passing $this->data to the View from Controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I'm using CakePHP 1.2 and I'm just wondering if there is any side affect on passing the $this->data to the View from the Controller.

Ex:

```
// inside PostsController, I have this code:
$this->data['Posts'] = $this->Post->find('all');
```

instead of :

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all');
$this->set(compact('posts'));

// inside the /posts/view, I access it like this:
<?php foreach ($this->data['Posts'] as $post) {....};?>
```

By doing this, I skipped the $this->set() from the controller all together. Does this violate any MVC pattern or any security issue that I might have overlook? I saw that using the Auth Component, $this->data contains the [_Token] array.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to be aware of the different places that Cake Helpers automagically look for data, since that is were it makes a real difference. The Form Helper will fill in fields automatically based on the contents of `$this->data`. That's how form data persists when validation fails. OTOH, a `<select>` elements options array is automatically taken from the pluralized field name,
e.g. `$form->select('Model.foo_id')` will take its options from `$foos` if set.

As such, `$this->data` has its special place and shouldn't be used lightly, just as named variables have their use and shouldn't be ignored. Use both as appropriate. If you don't want to auto-set Form Helper content, `set()` your variables. IMHO it's also more readable to assign a variable name that hints at the data it contains. All your views operating on `$this->data` is less clear than one view operating on `$foo` and another on `$bar`.

Answer (score 7):

In CakePHP **2.x** you should use `$this->request->data` instead if plain `$this->data`, otherwise you might end up getting this error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property View::$data has no effect

Answer (score 3):

`$controller->data` is meant for data posted to the control from view file.

`$view->data` is for general data.

I would avoid doing it to keep myself sane. besides you are typing more in view.

Comment: I agree with Funky Dude - $this->data, where $this is a model, controller, view or other object, I think should be for data posted from a form or read from a record in the db.

I think your version is far less readable and goes against the convention that everyone else is used to, making it far less portable.

But if you really want to save a line:
$this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));

Answer (score 2):

There is no good reason for setting $this->data directly except when working with forms.

Why break convention - Controller:set is there for a reason. If you want to pass data to the view for display or display logic purposes you should use the function provided instead of trying to co-opt Controller:data for unintended purposes.

Everything is easier from within CakePHP if you follow the rules and do things the expected, correct way.

Answer (score 2):

In `cakephp` version 2.*, error occurs when you try to set data on `$this->data`